# Errors were encountered while processing: tzdata

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have been installing Ubuntu on a not-so-old laptop, and when I tried to install a package, I got the `Errors were encountered while processing: tzdata`.

I have tried to do `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` but instead I got `tzdata is broken or not fully installed`. `apt install tzdata` acts like it will work, but when asked to confirm to install it fully, it will error because

```
dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata
```

AFAIK tzdata stands for TimeZoneDATA and trying to remove it warns me that Xserver and a bunch of others will be removed, and is a dependency of a ubuntu package.

It won't let me install anything but everything else works fine. Is there a way to solve this issue or make dpkg not care about it?

Comment: Have you tried installing it with the `--reinstall` flag?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; nor mentioned what occurs with `apt -f install` or other suggestions (`dpkg-reconfig..`).  You've only provided selected bits of some messages; there aren't any warnings further up the listing? as final error(s) can relate to earlier warnings/messages.

Comment: @Jos I think it worked! I can now install packages. Please write an answer so that I can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is in an inconsistent state, which means that only reinstalling will help. For this, you would normally first uninstall the package, but in this case that would mean uninstalling lots of vital packages that depend on it. Fortunately, there is a way to uninstall and reinstall in one go, without removing any other packages:

`sudo apt install --reinstall tzdata`

which apparently worked in your case.